# How to make invisible text visible with iText 4 in an existing pdf

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a PDF which is created by scanning software. One image per page and hidden OCR'ed text.
I want to remove the images and make the text visible.
I found info how to remove images (replace by another image) but found no way for making the invisible text visible.

[Sample PDF with image and hidden text](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=43169340344804983424)

I tried below method, but it does not work:

```
    Public Shared Sub UnhideText(ByVal strFileName As String)
    Dim pdf As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(strFileName)
    Dim stp As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(pdf, New IO.FileStream("e:\out.pdf", IO.FileMode.Create))

    'This does not work, text remains unvisible. I guess SetTextRenderingMode applies only for new added text.
    For pageNumber As Integer = 1 To pdf.NumberOfPages
        Dim cb As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte = stp.GetOverContent(pageNumber)
        cb.SetTextRenderingMode(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL)
    Next

    stp.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Depending on the ocr software used you probably cannot simply make the invisible text visible because different approaches are used for invisible text, among them fonts with each glyph an empty area... and sometimes the fonts are customized to contain cut out areas from the scanned image; in this case making them visible does not improve quality...

Comment: Share an example PDF then we might be able to help you...

Comment: I have added a link for a sample PDF. I guess the standard way for invisible text is TEXT_RENDER_MODE_INVISIBLE. My intention is not to improve quality (this is not possible when i just hide the scanned image and show the recognized text). I want to visualize how worse or how good the text recognition worked.